# android start activity with animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

Is it possible to ad an animation to an activity at runtime so when I start the activity, it starts with my animation? I want to specify some parameters to animation at runtime depending on some view's position. I've managed to ad an animation, but the animation was defined in a xml file so I was not able to edit the numbers from animation. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could define your animation in code instead of the XML file. For example [here](http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/13/android-animation-101/) it is explained how to do that. THen you can change things at runtime by using variables.

Comment: I wanted the animation for the activity, how to appear, not to a view... from what I've read there, it is for a view... I need that my activity to appear in a certain mode from certain screen coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you can always use the android activity life cycle to do this, in this case you can perform your animation in the onCreate function.

Cheers.

Comment: that's not the right answer. Yes, I can set the animation to the all layout, but then only the layout will be animated and when the activity will be opened, title will appear instantly and only layout containing all my views will be animated.

Comment: Did you try the _onFinishInflate_ method on the View class?